# prevent inputs from expanding to blocks in twitter-bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to see if anyone has a clean solution for keeping knockout from turning my form inputs that are styled with span* classes from turning into width 100% in fluid design.

When I go below 979 pixels, all of my span elements (i.e. span4) turn into 100% width.  This means that instead of having nicely styled forms in tablet views, I have tons of stacked 100% width text boxes.

I'm using bootstrap-responsive.css

Updated HTML Sample:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
         <input type="text" class="span5" placeholder="First" />
         <input type="text" class="span2" placeholder="Middle" />
         <input type="text" class="span5" placeholder="Last" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't want these elements to get stacked on top of each other when I view in a tablet.

Comment: can you show some of your html code sample?

Answer (score 1):

you can define your custom CSS for input tags under `@media (max-width: 979px) { ...}` inside your **bootstrap-responsive.css** in that css you can define width as you like